# random sampling with replacement of variables, not just cases

Tags: r, sampling, simulation, scales

I have k = 24 indicators for a latent construct.  In fact, these indicators are interchangeable. To reduce the number of indicators for a scale measuring the latent construct I would like to randomly sample k=18 (or k=12 or k=6) indicators from the original k=24 indicators.
Using random sampling with replacement, one might draw *many* samples (say, n = 1000)and then check if the statistics of interest (e.g. mean, variance, associations with external variables) change contingent on the number of k indicators.
The problem is that I’d like to sample from the variables - not from the cases. I would hence be very grateful if someone might help me with e.g. R code to tackle this task?
Best,
E.

Comment: As it stands, this seems to be primarily a question about programming   in R. If so, it is 'off topic' here. Are you asking whether this kind of random selection of independent variables is likely to be useful, or are you strictly asking for the R code to do it?

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply - and you are right, I am wondering how to implement the idea of random sampling of variables in R. I consider the approach itself valid, it would be one variant to construct a short scale (given invariant factor loadings of the indicators).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[R: Randomly sampling (with replacement) each column of a data frame independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982543/r-randomly-sampling-with-replacement-each-column-of-a-data-frame-independentl)

I created one example below:

```
df <- data.frame(age = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 22),
                 somethingelse = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 18),
                 smthelse2 = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 25))

df2 <- apply(df,
             MARGIN = 2,
             function(x) sample(x,
                                replace = TRUE,
                                size = length(x)))
```

Comment: Seems right (+1).